# org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "multipart/byteranges"

Tags: java, http, header

I am trying to get multipart range byte from AWS cloudfront by using `InvocationBuilder.header` like:

```
invocationBuilder.header("Range", "bytes=100-200,300-400,500-600\r");
```

but I got this :

```
Exception in thread "Name of the thread" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "multipart/byteranges; boundary=CloudFront:*number of file*"

Internal.InboundMessageContext.exception(InboundMessageContext.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.singleHeader(InboundMessageContext.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.getMediaType(InboundMessageContext.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:847)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
```

I tried to use curl from cmd and it works well. Anyone helps? Thanks.

Comment: I found that I did receive the HTTP response. Maybe it is the problem of readEntity(Class<T>), does anyone know how to read the multi-range response? String.class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront returns an invalid content-type header in their response to MultiPart range requests.

Specifically, the boundary parameter value contains a ":" which MUST be quoted.

I've just filed a bug with AWS, but we'll see what happens. That your original question is 5 years old does not fill me with confidence .

Example MultiPart request:

```
$ curl -vv https://foo.cloudfront.net/bar.bin -H "Range: bytes=1-100,150-200"
<snip>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 206 
< content-type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=CloudFront:32FA314F82E87793C3B34E2D1FCCE8ED
<snip>
```

Since they include a colon in their boundary parameter, then the parameter must be quoted like this:

```
< content-type: multipart/byteranges; boundary="CloudFront:32FA314F82E87793C3B34E2D1FCCE8ED"
```

This is according to [RFC1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521)

> WARNING TO IMPLEMENTORS: The grammar for parameters on the Content-
> type field is such that it is often necessary to enclose the
> boundaries in quotes on the Content-type line.  This is not always
> necessary, but never hurts.  Implementors should be sure to study the
> grammar carefully in order to avoid producing illegal Content-type
> fields. Thus, a typical multipart Content-Type header field might
> look like this:
>
> ```
>              Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>                   boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
> ```
>
> But the following is illegal:
>
> ```
>              Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>                   boundary=gc0p4Jq0M:2Yt08jU534c0p
> ```
>
> (because of the colon) and must instead be represented as
>
> ```
>              Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>                   boundary="gc0p4Jq0M:2Yt08jU534c0p"
> ```